# How to insert multiline text into mysql with PDO bind parameter method?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to insert a multiline text data to Blob type column.

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `msg` longblob NOT NULL
);
```

Addionally I post this text for saving into 'msg' column:

```
"This
is
Multiline
Text"
```

Inserting part is;

```
$mydata->mesaj = "This
is
Multiline
Text";
$sql =  "insert into messages(msg) values (:mesaj)";   
$stmt = $this->dbConnection->prepare($sql);     
$stmt->bindParam(':mesaj', $mydata->mesaj, PDO::PARAM_STR); /* Is it true for use PARAM_STR for longBlob type? */
try {
      $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
//..blah error blah
}
```

It does insert the text with out newlines. When i try to open blob record, it shows:

> ThisisMultilineText

I try replace \n with \n. Unfortunetely It was another unsuccesfull attempt too. Need an idea. i need to save with multiline text. Thank you,
Deniz

Comment: Have you tried $stmt->bindParam(':mesaj', $mydata->mesaj, PDO::PARAM_LOB); ?

Comment: @pendo, just tried and got same result. delete new line and concatanate the words. "ThisisMultilineText" :(

Comment: What are you using to read the data back out and display it?

Comment: If you're displaying the result of the query on a web page, it will wrap lines unless you put it in a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: I should've asked, why are you storing text you want to read as a blob?  That's not what it's for.  You usually would read the contents of a file as binary data and store that in the blob....not text.

Comment: Well its messaging app. Users share image, video, etc... I save all of them into the db. Thats why i use blob. PLUS even i convert column type to varchar, still reject newline char

Comment: What are you using to read the data back out and display it? You said _"When i try to open blob record"_ - what are you opening it with?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm curious as to what the problem was.

Comment: Yes Nick I solve this problem with unpleasant way. I am replacing  "\n" to "/n"  in mysql triggers. And I forbid "/" char in my system.(I mean I clear "/" char in sending messages or receiving messages). Its solve my problem but not satisfy me:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in what you are using to display the text. On my server with PHP7 and MySQL5.6 I created your table and then ran the following code (essentially the same as yours but with some minor variable name changes):

```
echo "<pre>";
$mesaj = "This
is
Multiline
Text";
$sql =  "insert into messages(msg) values (:mesaj)";   
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);     
$stmt->bindParam(':mesaj', $mesaj, PDO::PARAM_STR); /* Is it true for use PARAM_STR for longBlob type? */
try {
      $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
//..blah error blah
}
$result = $link->query('SELECT msg FROM messages WHERE id = 1');
if ($result) $row = $result->fetch();
echo $row['msg'] . "\n";
echo addcslashes($row['msg'], "\r\n");
```

And the output I get is (as expected):

```
This
is
Multiline
Text
This\r\nis\r\nMultiline\r\nText
```